# Fourier Transform of $(\operatorname{sinc}(x))^2\cdot \exp(-ax^2)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to calculate the FT of the following function:

$$(\operatorname{sinc}(x))^2\cdot \exp(-ax^2)$$

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how to do it directly, but my approach would be to expand the $\exp$-function and use the results for $\mathrm{sinc}(x)^2$ and $x^n f(x)$, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms).

Comment: @NickKidman It seems to be not well define. It turns out i have to evaluate the derivative of $tri(\xi)$!

Comment: Well, things could be worse.

Comment: @NickKidman I know but still I don't know how to solve it!